# How do I make a date field in Excel/LibreOffice Calc that is 180 days from today?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

So I have two columns, one is the current date (currently using a 09/06/15 format) and I have another column that is meant to be for a date 180 days into the future. How can I create a formula that will compute this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `=a1+180` and format the cell as a date. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dates to be automatically updated:

Current date: `=TODAY()`
180 days from now: `=TODAY()+180`